# Add Embedded slide into website html

Tags: php, html

I want to add Embedded slide but it's not working i added some animation in slider.
See the file [here](http://dmentor.co.in/I-Offer-My-Life-P1251091685ezwBL.ppsx)
I want to view it on website any idea or any player can support it
I'm using WordPress i want to make tutorial with it